# Gaps between list in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, list

I have created a vertical navigation that holds in buttons that I have created. There is a substantial gap between each button in IE and I can't work out why since all margins are 0! Very puzzled since it works fine in Chrome and FF.

```
#buttons {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 20px;
}
#buttons ul {
    display: inline;
}
#buttons ul li  {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 1px 0;
    clear:both;
}
#buttons ul li #quote{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
}

#buttons ul li a:hover #quote{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
    background-position: 270px 0px;
}
#buttons ul li #sample{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
    background-position: 0px 53px;
}

#buttons ul li a:hover #sample{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
    background-position: 270px 53px;
}
#buttons ul li #plan{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
    background-position: 0px 106px;
}

#buttons ul li a:hover #plan{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
    background-position: 270px 106px;
}
#buttons ul li #callback{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
    background-position: 0px 159px;
}

#buttons ul li a:hover #callback{
    width: 270px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: url('buttons.png');
    background-position: 270px 159px;
}

        <div id="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="openForm()"><div id="quote"></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div id="sample"></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div id="plan"></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div id="callback"></div></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you considered a reset style sheet? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Also what version of IE?

Comment: Just tried that, it helped slightly, still a big gap though. And IE 9, although I would like it to work up to IE 7 if possible!

Comment: Try setting the line height to 0, if removing the white space between the elements hasnt worked

Comment: The line-height solved it! Thanks very much DickieBoy

Answer (score 0):

Some older versions of IE don't like white space between `<li>` tags.

If you can access the HTML then you can get around this in a few ways.

Either comments:

```
<li>element One</li><!--
--><li>element Two</li><!--
--><li>element Three</li>...
```

Or single line lists:

```
<li>element One</li><li>element Two</li><li>element Three</li>...
```

Or you could try adding `vertial-align: bottom;` to all `<li>` tags.

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't worked! It's strange since it has never happened to me and my experience of making lists so I am confused to why it is doing this..

Comment: What version of IE? Can you set a JSFiddle up?